# On upgrade ag-grid version 19 from version 9, on right click tool panel option is not coming

Tags: ag-grid

On upgrade ag-grid version 19 from version 9, on right click tool panel option is not coming. 
Also we have an icon on click we opened a tool Panel for pivot that too is not working.

This is the current code we have on click of it.

This worked well for ag-Grid 9 but not working for ag-Grid 19

```js
this.preferencesService.togglePivot.subscribe(() => {
    const isOpen = this.gridOptions.api.isToolPanelShowing();
    if (isOpen) {
        this.gridOptions.columnApi.setColumnState(this.saveGridState);
        this.gridOptions.api.showToolPanel(false);
        this.gridOptions.api.setSideBarVisible(false);
        this.gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(false);
        // this.sideBar = false;
    } else {
        this.saveGridState = this.gridOptions.columnApi.getColumnState();
        this.gridOptions.api.showToolPanel(true);
        this.gridOptions.api.setSideBarVisible(true);
        // this.sideBar = 'columns';
        this.gridOptions.columnApi.setPivotMode(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you attach a fiddle with it

Comment: Please see sample code here - https://plnkr.co/edit/aMyQVnbKTuD1luUKo7gt?p=preview
Even if i set sidebar = 'columns' it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `[sideBar]="true"` for the toolbar to display.

Check this [updated plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/M3RmKb2sGdPu4CkCFOXp?p=preview)

Reference: [Boolean Configuration](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#boolean-configuration)

---

Update:

I tried many combinations to make it closed by default setting some parameter. Anyways, you could achieve it by using `gridApi`. Check the plunk, I have updated it.

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridApi.closeToolPanel();
}
```

Comment: Yes this works but it opens the side bar by default on during load of ag-Grid. I don't want the side bar to open by default, it should open only on button click.

Comment: @SDeveloper - have u got the solution?

Comment: Thank you for the answer
Yes it works on plunker but when i try in my project still not working.
In my project code, we have one pivot icon which we subscribe, i try to open tool panel using below code -
this.gridOptions.api.openToolPanel('columns');
Seems some issue with this, still trying out to find the issue

Answer (score 0):

[Here's the details](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/) about sideBar/toolPanel configuration.

sideBar can be more than just true or false.

Answer (score 0):

`setSideBarVisible` did not work properly for me, instead I've got `toggle` method which sets and unsets the sidebar as below

```js
toggleSideBar(): void {
    this.gridOptions.api.setSideBar(this.gridOptions.api.getSideBar() ? null : this.sideBar());
}
```