# ag-grid V19 hidden / closed tool panel by default

Tags: ag-grid

I am using the follwoing dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
   "ag-grid-community": "19.0.0",
   "ag-grid-angular": "19.0.0",
   "ag-grid-enterprise": "19.0.0",
}
```

After migrating to version 19 the new sidebar was hidden. This could be fixed by setting [sideBar]="'columns'".

But the tool panel section is always open. I could close it by calling gridApi.closeToolPanel(), but in this case you see the open toolPanel for a short moment if you load the page. Is there an option to show only the side bar buttons and hide the toolPanel by default (as it was in version 18)?

Answer (score 21):

```
var gridOptions = {    
sideBar: {
    toolPanels: [
            {
                id: 'columns',
                labelDefault: 'Columns',
                labelKey: 'columns',
                iconKey: 'columns',
                toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel',
                toolPanelParams: {
                    suppressValues: true,
                    suppressPivots: true,
                    suppressPivotMode: true,
                    suppressRowGroups: false
                }
            },
            {
                id: 'filters',
                labelDefault: 'Filters',
                labelKey: 'filters',
                iconKey: 'filter',
                toolPanel: 'agFiltersToolPanel',
            }
        ],
        defaultToolPanel: ''
    }
};
```

The defaultTooPanel: '' is what tells ag-grid what should be opened by default.  You can set it to blank or null and that will it cause it to not open any toolPanel by default.

Note: in version 19.0.0, you will get a console.log warning about this.
In 19.1.1, you will not get the warning.

Comment: very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

[To keep](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-side-bar/#sidebardef-configuration) the `ToolPanel` closed by default, you need to set the  `defaultToolPanel` to an empty string value.

```
        sideBar: {
            toolPanels: [
                {
                    id: "columns",
                    labelDefault: "Columns",
                    labelKey: "columns",
                    iconKey: "columns",
                    toolPanel: "agColumnsToolPanel",
                },
                {
                    id: "filters",
                    labelDefault: "Filters",
                    labelKey: "filters",
                    iconKey: "filter",
                    toolPanel: "agFiltersToolPanel",
                },
            ],
            defaultToolPanel: "",
        }
```

This is as the [default](https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/blob/master/packages/ag-grid-community/src/ts/entities/sideBar.ts#L49) value for `defaultToolPanel` is `columns`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on exactly where you are calling `gridApi.closeToolPanel()`.

Check [this plunk I've created](https://plnkr.co/edit/M3RmKb2sGdPu4CkCFOXp?p=preview). It's for angular, but I hope you will be able understand.

Call the funciton inside `onGridReady`.

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  this.gridApi.closeToolPanel();
}
```

Another similar kind of question: [On upgrade ag-grid version 19 from version 9, on right click tool panel option is not coming.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52967180/1417185)

Answer (score -1):

For some reasons this.gridApi.closeToolPanel() doesn't work at all time but I tried hacking it using:

```
onGridReady(params) {
  this.gridApi = params.api;
  settimeout(() => { this.gridApi.closeToolPanel()},100)
}
```